# How to Make Something Happen at a certain point in a Roblox Animation

Tags: lua, roblox

I'musing Roblox Studio and can't figure out how to make it print 'test' at a certain point in the animation. Here is the code:

```
animationTrackTwo:GetKeyframeReachedSignal("Throw"):Connect(function(value)
    print("test")
end)

local animationTrackTwo = character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(script.Parent.ThrowSnowball)
animationTrackTwo:Play()
```

I think i inserted a keyframe into the animation called 'Throw" (I may have done it wrong) but it says `GetKeyframeReachedSignal` is not a valid member of animationTrack. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the :GetMarkerReachedSignal() function, More information can be found at: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/AnimationTrack/GetMarkerReachedSignal